# get text of clicked element pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**get an element from the drop-down menu and replace into button value.**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("ul").classList.toggle("show");
}
var select = document.getElementById('ul');
var array = ["html", "css", "js", "jquery", "Angularjs"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute('href', '#');
  li.appendChild(link);
  var text = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
  link.appendChild(text);
  select.insertBefore(li, select.childNodes[i]);
}
```

Comment: cannot understand anything from the problem description

Comment: @brk run this code dropdown list is open then click on HTML, then this HTML go to button. This i need.

Comment: @asadminhas I think you missed html code to fully describe your problem. Please use https://jsfiddle.net to explain.

Comment: @imEnCoded <ul class=ul></ul> only html code.

Comment: @asadminhas if `<ul class=ul></ul>` is the html code then you should get error when calling `myFunction`

Answer (score 0):

**USE OTHER ID NAMING**

It sounds bad to give an element an id of 'ul', id should be more specific and semantic.

**JS QUERY FOR RELEVANT DOM CONTENT**

Also, you wrote in your comment that you HTML ul tag has 'class' not 'id', but then in your question, you query the DOM by id. Hence, either you have to change your HTML so your ul tag has some id or you have to change your function to query the DOM by class ie `documentGetElementByClass('some_class')` -> notE that this produce array so you get the reference by indexing it, ie the first element in DOM is `documentGetElementByClass('some_class')[0]`. Then, if your HTML trully is only one-liner such as you commented `<ul></ul>` you rather query your DOM by tagname like this `documentGetElementByTagname('ul')[0]`.

**GET YOUR DICTIONARY CORRECTED**

You ask about replacing drop-down menu into button value, but your code suggest that you just work with links in a form of 'a' tag and that you manipulate their href attributes -> this has nothing to do with buttons. Buttons are either paired tags  or self-closing tags .